# Easy way to check if my batch file has been opened

Tags: batch-file, connection

So i am making a program in batch (cmd) that i will be sharing to other people outside of my network and i would like
to know if a computer has run the program and get my computer to alert me.

Thanks!

(Edited due to downvotes)

Comment: I don't see any batch file code to help you with. Not sure why you are referring to any networking terminology.

Comment: I can think of several ways: writing to a logfile, write to registry, writing to eventlog...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I noticed that you asked about people *outside* your network, here is my answer:

You will need a server. [Download ApacheHaus httpd server for Windows](http://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx) and extract the `Apache24` directory to `c:\`

Make this script and save it as `confirmed.bat` to your `cgi-bin` directory on your new server...

```
@echo off
echo content-type: text/plain
echo.
echo Your Program Was Installed on %REMOTE_ADDR%'s computer at %DATE% %TIME% >> %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\desktop\ALERT.TXT
echo Hello, World!
exit
```

Now, add this line to your batch file:

```
iexplore "http://<<<your server's IP address>>>/cgi-bin/confirmed.bat"
```

And there you go! Google some stuff if you're still confused.

~CSS